# C++ Issue passing String value to Implementation file

Tags: c++, string, class

Having troubles with a homework assignment. C++ is not my best language and I'm struggling with the class especially with the concept of classes. I think I have mostly worked the code out for the assignment, but I have am having difficulties passing the string romanString2 from the main file to the implementation file so it reaches void romanType::romanToPositiveInteger() {}. Below is my current code. I would appreciate assistance in pointing what is wrong.

main.cpp
//Main program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "roman.h" 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    romanType roman;

    string romanString2;

    cout << "Enter a roman number: ";
    cin >> romanString2;
    cout << endl;
     roman.setRoman(romanString2);

    cout << "The equivalent of the Roman numeral "
         << romanString2 << " is ";
    roman.printPositiveInteger();
   // cout << numResult;
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

roman.cpp
//Roman Number Implementation file

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include "roman.h"

using namespace std;

// part c
void romanType::printPositiveInteger() const { 
cout << num; 
}

// part c
void romanType::printRoman() const {
cout << romanNum;
}

// part a
void romanType::setRoman(string rString) {
    romanNum = rString;
     romanToPositiveInteger(); 
}

// part b
void romanType::romanToPositiveInteger() {

    int numResult;
    string romanString;
    numResult = 0;

   cout << romanString;
    if (romanString.find("MMM") != std::string::npos) {
   numResult = numResult + 3000;
}else if (romanString.find("MM") != std::string::npos){
         numResult = numResult + 2000;
    }else if (romanString.find("M") != std::string::npos and romanString.find("CM") == std::string::npos){

         numResult = numResult + 1000;
    }else{

    }
    if (romanString.find("CM") != std::string::npos){
        numResult = numResult + 900;
        cout << "CM";
    }
       if (romanString.find("D") != std::string::npos and romanString.find("CD") == std::string::npos) {
   numResult = numResult + 500;
}

     if (romanString.find("CD") != std::string::npos){
        numResult = numResult + 400;
    }

           if (romanString.find("C") != std::string::npos and romanString.find("CD") == std::string::npos and romanString.find("CC") == std::string::npos  and romanString.find("CCC") == std::string::npos and romanString.find("CM") == std::string::npos  ) {
   numResult = numResult + 100;
}
        if (romanString.find("CCC") != std::string::npos) {
   numResult = numResult + 300;
}else if (romanString.find("CC") != std::string::npos){
         numResult = numResult + 200;
    }

              if (romanString.find("L") != std::string::npos and romanString.find("LC") == std::string::npos) {
   numResult = numResult + 50;
}
    if(romanString.find("XL") != std::string::npos) {
   numResult = numResult + 40;
}
        if (romanString.find("XXX") != std::string::npos) {
   numResult = numResult + 30;
}else if (romanString.find("XX") != std::string::npos){
         numResult = numResult + 20;
    }else if (romanString.find("X") != std::string::npos and romanString.find("IX") == std::string::npos){

         numResult = numResult + 10;
    }else{

    } 
      if (romanString.find("IX") != std::string::npos){
        numResult = numResult + 9;
    } 
      if (romanString.find("V") != std::string::npos and romanString.find("IV") == std::string::npos ){
        numResult = numResult + 5;
    } 
        if (romanString.find("III") != std::string::npos) {
   numResult = numResult + 3;
}else if (romanString.find("II") != std::string::npos){
         numResult = numResult + 2;
    }else if (romanString.find("I") != std::string::npos and romanString.find("IV") == std::string::npos){

         numResult = numResult + 1;
    }else{

    }
      if (romanString.find("IV") != std::string::npos){
        numResult = numResult + 4;
    } 
    cout << numResult;
     num = numResult;
}

romanType::romanType() { 
romanNum ='I';
    num='1';

}

romanType::romanType(string rString) { 
    romanNum = rString;
     romanToPositiveInteger();
}
```

roman.h

```
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

class romanType
{
public:
    void setRoman(string);
    void romanToPositiveInteger();
    void printPositiveInteger() const;
    void printRoman() const;
    romanType();
    romanType(string);


private:
    string romanNum;
    int num;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One error I noticed:

You are using

```
void romanType::romanToPositiveInteger() {

    int numResult;
    string romanString;
    numResult = 0;
```

and proceeding with the assumption that `romanString` contains the string representation of the roman number.

That information is stored in the member variable `romanNum`. Change the usages of `romanString` by `romanNum` in function and remove the variable `romanString` altogether.

Comment: Thanks, I have it working now.  I had a feeling it was something obvious but I was getting so frustrated with it that I probably wouldn't have noticed the error even if it started flashing red.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the string in variable romanNum but in romanToPositive function you are using a local string variable romanString instead of romanNum variable. That's the reason you are not seeing the desired output